# How can I change a Symfony exception response code

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

- Symfony 3.4
- PHP 7.4

I am trying to map

`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Exception\SuspiciousOperationException`

to another response code. Basically like Laravel did: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/29000/files

Currently it creates a fatal error and 500 response:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Exception\SuspiciousOperationException: ...`

I want to return a `404` as response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do like in Laravel, you should take a look at [Event Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener).

```
public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
{
    // You get the exception object from the received event
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    
    // Customize your response object to display the exception details
    $response = new Response();

    if ($exception instanceof SuspiciousOperationException) {
        $response->setStatusCode(404);
    } else {
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    // sends the modified response object to the event
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: In symfony 4+ you also need to add `$event->allowCustomResponseCode();`

Comment: Here I wrote article How we carried out by Listener

https://medium.com/@mukhiddin-jumaniyazov/symfony-custom-error-exception-response-fee4d51c29bf